# A functional equation AIME

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A certain function $f$ has the properties that $f(3x) = 3f(x)$ for all positive real values of $x$, and that $f(x) = 1-|x-2|$ for $1\le x \le 3$. Find the smallest $x$ for which $f(x) = f(2001)$.

I figured out the fact that f(2001) is equal to 186 by iterating the function multiple times. I am however confused about how I can progress further and find the **smallest** possible value